# How to get textbox on MS Access report to continue onto second page

Tags: microsoft-access, database, format, report

I have a database that involves notes about client interactions.  The notes are stored in a memo field, so, they can range in length from short to very long.  On my Report, I have inserted a textbox with the Can Grow field set to yes.  This displays the client notes just fine until the length of the note extends such that the textbox grows so large that extends beyond the footer and beyond the bottom of the page and is ultimately truncated.

How can I get the textbox text to extend onto the next page?  Surely there must be many folks with this sort of need, so, I am hoping there is an answer.  I am happy to do some VBA coding if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was solved when I removed a page-break control that was posted below other controls later on the report.  Apparently the page-break control prevented a page break from automatically occurring and instead would only add a page break at the page-break control instead.

Oddly, the problem also disappeared when I added a subreport after the memo textbox and before the page-break control.

At any rate, trying removing any manual page-break controls if you are having a similar problem with memo textboxes appearing over the footer and not continuing onto the next page.